# Deployment with Deployment manager

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to auto-deploy an application to a newly installed Websphere ND with Deployment Manager.
This is what I just did:

1. Install WebSphere
2. manageProfiles create, profile name="deployer", template = management, profile type = DEPLOYMENT_MANAGER, cell="ndcell", node="ndnode"
3. manageProfiles create, profile name="app", template = default, cell = knowncell, node = knownnode
4. AppServer/profiles/deployer/bin/startManager.sh
5. AppServer/profiles/app/bin/addNode.sh hostname (this all happens on one same host "hostname")
6. AppServer/bin/wsadmin -c '$AdminConfig modify [$AdminConfig showAttribute [$AdminConfig getid /Cell:ndcell] monitoredDirectoryDeployment] {{enabled true}}' - turn on monitored directory deployment
7. AppServer/bin/wsadmin -c '$AdminConfig save'
8. AppServer/profiles/deployer/bin/stopManager.sh, then startManager.sh

All right, at this point admin console shows one server "server1" which is not started, and there exists the directory AppServer/profiles/deployer/monitoredDeployableApps, that's the good part. The bad part is the directory is empty! There is no "server1" dir there, as it should be, to put my EAR into.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm assuming by "cell = knowncell, node = knownnode" you meant "cell = ndcell, node = ndnode"?

Comment: No it's different cell/node. On addNode, the node gets injected into ndcell anyway, isn't it? I thought if I created server1 in ndcell initially, adding it to a cell would have no sense, since it's already in that cell. Did I get that wrong?

Comment: But thinking of it now, does executing addNode mean that "app" profile now belongs to cell ndcell instead of knowncell?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a full synchronize in order to Dmgr deem changes to take effect

Comment: I am pretty sure  I tried that: syncing the node, then restarting the manager. To no good. On the other hand you are right, I also tried manual installation of the app and was not able to start app till I resynced the node.

Comment: By the way. If I have monitored directories, there such dirs both in deployment manager and in "app" profile, aren't they? Does that mean I can either install app via depl mgr (propagating to all the nodes) or to a specific node? The same question applies to installing via console or wsadmin: how do they understand where do I want to install my app?

Comment: ... is it simply determined by which profile do I connect with wsadmin and which console (dmgr's or server's) I log in to?

Comment: Those folders are both for deployment purposes. The Dmgr deploy app folder is in which the ear, war... file is stored when you upload it for deploying, and when you deploy it into a specific AppServer, the file will be stored in the corresponding AppServer's app folder. It's you who indicates where do you want to install your app (in which AppServer) by command (or selecting via console). There's only one console, Dmgr's, there is not server console. Maybe you have to read a bit about Dmgr role, I think your problem here comes from the fact you don't undesrtand pretty well how WebSphere works.

Comment: Well, I would not ask dumb questions if I was able to derive answers from what little sources I managed to find on dmgr :) OK, but in that case, of what use is dmgr? I could do the same thing without dmgr :) What "deployment management" does dmgr perform, if I still have to manually issue commands to install application A on servers B, C and D? Maybe my benefit is that app-to-server binding is stored on dmgr, and if I just replace my server B with another empty one, I don't have to say again "run A on it", but dmgr will automatically push A there?